# Sandwich theorem. Showing that a sequence is sandwiched.

Tags: calculus

I am quite confused with how to go about doing the sandwich theorem.

The question is:

> Show that the sequence $X_n=n!$ is sandwiched by the sequences $a_n=2^{n-1}$ and $b_n=n^n$.

My question is: do I just find the limits of all $3$ sequences and if it's the same, it means that $X_n$ is sandwiched or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Do you mean [math]2^{n- 1}[/math]?

Comment: This probably isn't about limits since the sequences diverge to infinity. Rather you just want to show that $ 2^{n-1} \leq n! \leq n^n $. Well, each of these has an obvious way to factorize it into n factors, and you can then compare the expressions factor by factor.

Comment: Oh, so i dont have to find the limits? I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: @MeatforGeeks The limits do not exist. All three sequences diverge to $\infty$. This was probably the cause for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{n-1}\le n!\quad(*)$

Indeed it is true for $n=1$ because $2^0=1!$

Now suppose $(*)$ is true for $N$ and let's prove it for $n+1$

$2^n=2\cdot 2^{n-1}\le 2\cdot n! \le (n+1)\cdot n!=(n+1)!$

Consider now 
$n!\le n^n\quad(**)$

is true for $n=1$ because $1!=1^1$

Suppose $(**)$ holds for $n$ and let's prove it for $n+1$

$(n+1)!=(n+1)n!\le (n+1)n^n=n^{n+1}+n^n\ldots\quad(***)$

Now for the binomial rule $(n+1)^{n+1}=n^{n+1} + n\cdot n^n+\ldots$ therefore

$(***)n^{n+1}+n^n\le n^{n+1} + n\cdot n^n<(n+1)^{n+1}$

so $(**)$ is proved for any $n$ and it is possible to state that for any $n$

$$2^{n-1}\le n!\le n^n$$

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks!